# Age verification based on birthdate and current date

Tags: javascript, react-native

So, I need to calculate age by subtracting "todays" date from the converted date of an input field, entered by the user. Although it needs cleaned up, the below code works, I had to get creative as RN uses a different JS execution environment... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874676/react-native-code-doesnt-work-without-remote-debugger-enabled).

My question, without adding the "+1" to this snippet "b.getMonth() + 1", the math on the date subtraction comes back 1 month off every time. When I add the "+1" it works like a charm, why? If it's a logical fix, I don't mind keeping the "+1," but I would surely like to know why the "+1" is necessary.

Also, totally open to improved solutions to this problem, keep in mind I had a much simpler function that worked great while debugger was open, once closed, it did not work, see the link above.

```
getVerifyBirthday(birthday) {
    const b = new Date();
    var verify = birthday.length;

    const utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth() + 1, b.getDate());

    if (verify === 10) {
      const splitBirth = birthday.split('-');
      var mydate = new Date(splitBirth[2], splitBirth[0], splitBirth[1]);

      const a = mydate;
      const utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());

      const diffTime = Math.abs(utc2 - utc1);
      const diffYears = (diffTime / (3.15576e+10));

      this.setState({ diffYears: diffYears});

      return diffYears >= 13;
    } else {}
  }
```

**Update**

I ended up refactoring my original function, leaving the (+1) on months due to months starting at 0, as mentioned below. I still had to split both dates, when I didn't split both, my age came back NaN/Undefined; not sure if this goes back to the RN execution environment vs browser, but I digress.

Comment: Months are counted from 0 - that's the way `Date` works

Comment: `Javascript` returns the month 0 to 11, so `+1` is required

Comment: date strings formatted as `mm-dd-yyyy` are perfectly fine parsed by `new Date()`, so, actually, there's no need to `split()`, besides fighting for timezone precision doesn't make sense, since eventually you make your decision based on whether 13 times 365.25 days have passed, but this should depend on actual leap years quantity, so precision is lost at that part of the code so, there's no point in whole UTC-thing, whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Since months start with 0, do years and days also start with 0? Meaning, do i need to do a +1 on those as well or just months?

Comment: As for years and days - you don't need to `+1` those.

Comment: The `Date` API was one of the worst parts of the initial design of JS.  0-based months, 1-based days, everything mutable, year/fullYear.  It's an unholy mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a few of my own suggestions over here:

- there's no need to hussle with UTC dates (to make sure whether the user ***in his timezone*** has already reached the age of 13, assuming along the way that he or she was born in that same timezone ;)
- there's no need to split `mm-dd-yyyy` date string to convert into `Date`, it may be parsed by `new Date()`
- counting years as 365.25 days has certain error margin depending on the exact leap years quantity that passed since the user's birth year, instead whole years may be compared together with dates

To me, it makes more sense to decompose date strings into days, months and years and make decision based on full years difference minus 1 year (if the person didn't yet celebrate his/her birthday this year):

```js
const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10), // yyyy-mm-dd
      birthday = '1982-06-21',
      [bYear, bMonth, bDay] = birthday.split('-'),
      [tYear, tMonth, tDay] = today.split('-'),
      diffYears = tYear - bYear - (bMonth > tMonth || bDay > tDay ? 1 : 0)

console.log(diffYears)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: This snippet results to NaN

Comment: This works in a normal browser, but not in my RN app. As I mentioned above, there are different execution environments for each; in browser it works great, in my simulator it still results to NAN. Unless I implemented this incorrectly, this is the initial issue I had begin with. Cleaning up my original function and including the (+1) seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Months are zero-based in JavaScript Date objects. However, if you get a formatted string, they start from `1`:

```js
const date = new Date(2020, 1, 17); // 17th of February 2020

console.log("getMonth:", date.getMonth());     //month is 1
console.log("formatted:", date.toISOString()); //month is 2
```

So, actually what happens is that you're *shifting both dates a month forward*. This sort of works:

```js
const originDate = new Date(2020, 1, 17); // 17th of February 2020
const originString = "2020-02-17".split("-");

const dateFromDate = new Date(originDate.getFullYear(), originDate.getMonth() + 1, originDate.getDate())
const dateFromString = new Date(originString[0], originString[1], originString[2])

console.log("dateFromDate:", dateFromDate);     //month is 3
console.log("dateFromString:", dateFromString); //month is 3
```

When you do the subtraction it evens out but you can still run into an overflow of the date for months with different number of days:

```js
const originDate = new Date(2020, 0, 31);   // 31st of January 2020

const dateFromDate = new Date(originDate.getFullYear(), originDate.getMonth() + 1, originDate.getDate())

console.log("dateFromDate:", dateFromDate); // 1st of March 2020
```

This still works logically for most cases, however you are bound to run into a problem at some point if you shift months forward. So, instead you should be doing the opposite and *subtracting* `1` when converting a 1-based number into a Date object:

```js
const originString = "2020-02-17".split("-");

const dateFromString = new Date(originString[0], originString[1] - 1, originString[2])

console.log("dateFromString:", dateFromString); //month is 2
```